# O que é a função CSS element()?

Tags: css

Recentemente li sobre essa função ainda experimental, num primeiro momento, me pareceu algo semelhante ao `document.querySelector` do JavaScript, onde seria possível acessar informações de um nó do DOM diretamente pelo CSS, mas, lendo um pouco mais, tive a impressão que ele é bem limitado e não oferece muitas funcionalidades

Então queria saber, o que essa função faz e o que ela traz de novo?

Comment: *Recentemente li sobre essa nova função"* pode editar a pergunta e colocar o link se tiver? é que `element()` já existe há um bom tempo (aqui o link de 2017):  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#element-notation

Comment: @RicardoPontual deduzi ser nova já que é uma tecnologia experimental (segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element())), editei a pergunta pra exclarecer isso

Answer (score 3):

A função CSS `element()` "clona" um outro elemento e transforma sua cópia em uma imagem. Essa função é comumente usada dentro da propriedade `background`, e não vi ela ser usada em outra situação além dessa.

Ela é útil para criar alguns efeitos de clonagem de elementos, como um elemento fantasma ou um reflexo do que foi copiado. Ele deve ser utilizado da seguinte maneira:

```css
background: element(#elementoCopiado);
```

E aqui está um breve exemplo do uso desta função:

```css
.reflection {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 215px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.reflection-text {
  font: 1.2em sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
  color: #000;
  transition: padding .3s;
}
.reflection:hover .reflection-text {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.reflection::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 100%;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  background: -moz-element(#css-element);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  mask: url('#mask');
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<figure class="reflection" id="css-element">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/300/215?image=84" alt="">
  <figcaption class="reflection-text">San Francisco, CA</figcaption>
</figure>
<svg height="0">
  <mask id="mask">
    <rect width="100%" height="215" fill="url(#gradient)"/>
    <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="gradient">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </mask>
</svg>
```

Essa função é originalmente chamada `-moz-element()` e foi encurtada para `element()`. Trata-se de uma funcionalidade experimental presente em navegadores Gecko (como o Mozilla Firefox) e **não está presente nos outros navegadores.**

---

Fontes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/element()

https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-element-function

Comment: Além disso, essa não é uma função "nova". Ela está presente no Firefox desde a versão 4 (lançada em Maio de 2011).